# Imaging Backend not working in eucalyptus

Tags: eucalyptus

I have installed eucalyptus 4.4.4 on Centos 7 and I have already done all installation steps but it is still showing "imagingbackend" as not ready.

Answer (score 0):

The imaging service is not always required when using eucalyptus. Particularly for smaller deployments it can be a good choice to skip configuration of the imaging service and save the resources (virtual machine instances) that would have been used by the imaging service for user workloads.

To enable the imaging service you need to install and register the service image (v5 output shown):

```
# esi-describe-images 
    SERVICE     VERSION  ACTIVE          IMAGE          INSTANCES 
    imaging     5.0.100    *     emi-b54e3b35170d2c56e      1     
 loadbalancing  5.0.100    *     emi-b54e3b35170d2c56e      0
```

and create the stack:

```
# esi-manage-stack -a check
Stack 'euca-internal-imaging-service' currently is in CREATE_COMPLETE state.
```

the steps to get to this state are covered in the documentation:

http://docs.eucalyptus.cloud/eucalyptus/4.4.5/index.html#install-guide/configure_imaging_service.html

You can also use esi-manage-stack to delete / create the imaging stack:

```
# esi-manage-stack -a delete
services.imaging.worker.configured = false
# esi-manage-stack -a create
Stack 'euca-internal-imaging-service' currently is in DELETE_IN_PROGRESS state. Please wait till the end of previous stack change operation.
# esi-manage-stack -a create
services.imaging.worker.configured = true
#
```

If you have gone through these steps but the service is not enabled you should do basic checks to verify that you can run any instances in your cloud:

```
# euca-describe-instance-types --show-capacity
# euserv-describe-events
```

and also check the log for errors /var/log/eucalyptus/cloud-debug.log